# Library for evaluating logical expressions on Java objects

Tags: java, expression, evaluate

Let's say I have the following class:

```
class Person {
    int age;
    String city;
    Collection<Person> friends;
    Person spouse;
}
```

I need a library which would allow me to evaluate whether a logical expression is true on a given Person object. The expression would look something like this:

```
((age>25 OR spouse.age>27) AND city=="New-York" AND size(friends)>100)
```

So, the requirements are:

1. Ability to use basic logical operators
2. Access properties of the given object
3. Access properties of an internal object
4. Use simple mathematical\sql-like functions such as size,max,sum

Suggestions?

Comment: Can you say why you can't use plain Java to do this? Does the expression have to come from a dynamic String?

Comment: why you don't write functions of your own??

Comment: Why you need any library for that??

Comment: Why do you need a library for anything? Because it is more complicated than it looks (mainly the parsing issues) and there are probably are tons of pitfalls you can run into which a solid library already eliminated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, think I found what I wanted, it's a variation on assylias' answer but I prefer it since it's more standardized (woudn't want to depend specifically on Javascript expressions, or run Javascript at all for that matter).

Apparently there is a [Unified Expression Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Expression_Language) for evaluating expressions, it was originally designed for JSP but can be used for other stuff as well. There are several parser implementations, I'll probably go either with [Spring EL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html) or [JUEL](http://juel.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [ScriptEngine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html) + reflection:

- access all the [fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) in your object and create variable that have those values
- evaluate the expression

Here is a contrived example which outputs:

```
age = 35
city = "London"
age > 32 && city == "London" => true
age > 32 && city == "Paris" => false
age < 32 && city == "London" => false
```

It could become quite messy if you want to deal with non primitive types, such as collections.

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Person p = new Person();
        p.age = 35;
        p.city = "London";

        ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

        Class<Person> c = Person.class;
        for (Field f : c.getDeclaredFields()) {
            Object o = f.get(p);
            String assignement = null;
            if (o instanceof String) {
                assignement = f.getName() + " = \"" + String.valueOf(o) + "\"";
            } else {
                assignement = f.getName() + " = " + String.valueOf(o);
            }
            engine.eval(assignement);
            System.out.println(assignement);
        }

        String condition = "age > 32 && city == \"London\"";
        System.out.println(condition + " => " + engine.eval(condition));

        condition = "age > 32 && city == \"Paris\"";
        System.out.println(condition + " => " + engine.eval(condition));

        condition = "age < 32 && city == \"London\"";
        System.out.println(condition + " => " + engine.eval(condition));
    }

    public static class Person {

        int age;
        String city;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **rhino library from Mozilla**. https://github.com/mozilla/rhino

Example :

```
@Test
public void shouldCheckLogicalOperations(){
    Context cx = Context.enter();
    try {
        Scriptable scope = cx.initStandardObjects();
        ScriptableObject.putProperty(scope, "form_admin_checked", true);
        ScriptableObject.putProperty(scope, "form_limit_value", 50000);

        String script = "((form_admin_checked && form_limit_value<2000) || (form_admin_checked && !form_admin_checked) || form_admin_checked && form_limit_value==50000)";
        String expectedResponse = "true";

        Object result = cx.evaluateString(scope, script, "<cmd>", 1, null);

        Assert.assertEquals(expectedResponse, result.toString());

    } finally {
        // Exit from the context.
        Context.exit();
    }
}
```